# Yii: Getting the most repeated id's from a certain table

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am a yiibie, and I am trying to run a query on the table named `user_join_event` by which I can get the 5 `user_id` which are most repeated in this table, so that I can have the 5 most active users id. The query is

```
SELECT `user_id`
  FROM `user_join_event`
 GROUP BY `user_id`
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
 LIMIT 5;
```

This query gives me the perfect result and I have transformed this query so that I can use it in yii which is:

```
$sql = Yii::app()
    ->db
    ->createCommand()
    ->select('user_id')
    ->from('user_join_event')
    ->group('user_id')
    ->order('COUNT(*) DESC')
    ->limit(4)
    ->queryAll()
```

Now after that I have made a allstats function in `UserJoinEvent` controller which is:

```
public function actionAllstats()
{
    $rbmodel = UserJoinEvent::model()->findAll();
    $this->layout = 'main';
    $sql = Yii::app()
        ->db
        ->createCommand()
        ->select('user_id')
        ->from('user_join_event')
        ->group('user_id')
        ->order('COUNT(*) DESC')
        ->limit(4)
        ->queryAll();

        $this->render('allstats', array("sql" => $sql, "rbmodel" => $rbmodel));
}
```

And a `allstat.php` (in the view file of UserJoinEvent) which is:

```
<div>
    <?php foreach ($rbmodel as $show): ?>
        <h3><?php echo $show->user_id?></h3>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

so that I can have the top 5 members id on this view page. But now, according to this code it is giving me all the `user_id` from the `UserJoinEvent` table instead of the 5 id's which are most repeated in the table. Please help me in getting the 5most repeated user's id. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should get the model only by the query and use them, (In your view you are echo the result of a full access to the UserJoinTAble) 
try modifing you code in this way

```
    public function actionAllstats()
            {

        $this->layout='main';
        $user=UserJoinEvent::model()->findAll(array(
                'select'=>'user_id',
                'group'=>'user_id',
                'order'=>'COUNT(*) DESC',
                'limit' =>  4
             ));  
        $this->render('allstats', array("user"=>$user));
            }


    And a allstat.php(in the view file of UserJoinEvent) which is

    <div>
        <?php
            foreach($user as $show)
            {
                echo '<h3>' . $show->user_id . '</h3>';
            }
        ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: It is giving an error here echo '<h3>' . $show->user_id . '</h3>'; that "Trying to get property of non-object "

Comment: I have upodate the answer using find all based on UserJoinModel. I hope this is the right way..

Comment: I have one more thing to ask, as i have got the id of the user, can i also get the name of the user against that id on the view page..??

Comment: Give ten minutes i'm thinking the simplest way.. please tell  from which model you get the name

Comment: I get the name from the user model

Comment: I have find a simple solution post another question and comment me the link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373652/yii-get-the-name-of-the-user-against-ther-id