# Yii: SQL query for getting the top users for every month and top users at the end of year

Tags: mysql, yii

I am a yiibie, I have a question that I have a table named user_join_event which has `id(PK)` `ngo_id(FK)` `event_id(FK)` `date_created` `date_modified` as objects, and I want to get the 5 users Id's(which are repeated the most in this table) for every month. Like January top 5 users, Feb top 5 users and so on and then the top 5 users at the end of the year from this table, like once the year is completed it should give again the top 5 users from all over the month. Please help me with this, how to write an SQL query for this, thank you.

```
 public function actionAllstats()
            {

        $this->layout='main';
        $user=UserJoinEvent::model()->findAll(array(
            'condition' => 'YEAR(date_created)=:year and MONTH(date_created)=:month',
            'param' => array(':year'=>2015, ':month'=>$yourMonth),
            'select'=>'user_id',
            'group'=>'user_id',
            'order'=>'COUNT(*) DESC',
            'limit' =>  5
         ));  
        $this->render('allstats', array("user"=>$user));
            }
```

and this is my view file

```
<div>
    <?php

        foreach($user as $show)
        {
            for($i = 1 ; $i <=12 ; $i++)
            {
                if($yourMonth == $i)
                {
                    $model = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$show->user_id,));
           if (isset($model)) 
               {
               echo '<h3>' . $show->user_id .  ' - ' . $model->username . '</h3>';
           } 
           else {
               echo '<h3>' . $show->user_id .  ' - Username not found</h3>';
           } 
                }
            }

        }

        ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: which date you think to use for the and mnoth and year filter? dat_created?, date_modified?

Comment: 30th date for the end of the month and year.

Comment: NO. i need to know the name of the field .. date_created or date_modified?

Comment: i need to use "date_created" mate.

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge can you please help me with this when you get free, Thank you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34462524/yii-how-to-show-dynamic-bootstrap-progress-bars-on-view-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Year you can sue this query for getting the users

```
       $user=UserJoinEvent::model()->findAll(array(
            'condition' => 'YEAR(date_create)=:year',
            'params' => array(':year'=>2015)
            'select'=>'user_id',
            'group'=>'user_id',
            'order'=>'COUNT(*) DESC',
            'limit' =>  5
         ));
```

and for the month you can do a loop from 1 to 12 using this query and set $yourMonth withe the value in loop

```
       $user=UserJoinEvent::model()->findAll(array(
            'condition' => 'YEAR(date_create)=:year and MONTH(date_create)=:month',
            'params' => array(':year'=>2015, ':month'=>$yourMonth )
            'select'=>'user_id',
            'group'=>'user_id',
            'order'=>'COUNT(*) DESC',
            'limit' =>  5
         ));
```

**Controller action**

```
public function actionAllstats()
{

    $this->layout='main';
    $myCurrYear = date("Y")
    $userYear=UserJoinEvent::model()->findAll(array(
        'condition' => 'YEAR(date_create)=:year',
        'params' => array(':year'=>$myCurrYear)
        'select'=>'user_id',
        'group'=>'user_id',
        'order'=>'COUNT(*) DESC',
        'limit' =>  5
     ));  
    $this->render('allstats', array("userYear"=>$userYear));
}
```

**View**

*This view in not based on good pratice, because use access to model inside a view. is a trial for lead you to understand some of the problem related with question.*

```
<?php    // this for the twelve month

    for($month = 1 ; $month <=12 ; $month++) {
    <div>
        $user=UserJoinEvent::model()->findAll(array(
            'condition' => 'YEAR(date_created)=:year and MONTH(date_created)=:month',
            'params' => array(':year'=>2015, ':month'=>$month),
            'select'=>'user_id',
            'group'=>'user_id',
            'order'=>'COUNT(*) DESC',
            'limit' =>  5
         ));    
        foreach($user as $show) {
            $model = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$show->user_id,));
            if (isset($model)) {
                echo '<h3>' . $show->user_id .  ' - ' . $model->username . '</h3>';
            } 
             else {
                echo '<h3>' . $show->user_id .  ' - Username not found</h3>';
            } 
        }
    </div>            
    }
?>


<div>   
    <?php // the for the year 
        foreach($userYear as $show) {
            $model = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$show->user_id,));
            if (isset($model)) {
                echo '<h3>' . $show->user_id .  ' - ' . $model->username . '</h3>';
            } 
             else {
                echo '<h3>' . $show->user_id .  ' - Username not found</h3>';
            } 
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but where do i have to use the loop, in my view file or here in the query or just i have to paste this code and test it..??
Actually i don't have idea how to use it in my solution,

Comment: for the Year you should use the code in answer in sobstitution on analog query you used in some previous answer. For month you should perform the loop in your view..Is like you want repateat the query twelve times.. If i remenber well you should have already a view for this kind of query.Copy that and try to adapt to you need..

Comment: Okay and one last question, you have specified this query for 2015, what if 2016 comes, will this query work..!!

Comment: You should use the current year eg :    $myCurrYear = date("Y"); and obviuosly use $myCurYear instead of 2015

Comment: Thank you so much, i will test it and let you know..!!

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge, i have tried the answer and i have edited the question with the code i have been trying, but i gives me an error "undefined varibale:yourMonth" and i also do not have idea of how to get the current year which you tole me last night( $myCurrYear = date("Y"). Please help me in getting the data on my view page, thank you.

Comment: You want all the stats in a single page? twelve div for months and a div for year. ?

Comment: yes exactly i want all stats on a single page, twelve div for months and a div for year on a single page and sorry for late response, i was having some internet connection issues.

Comment: And once i get the username and id's I will show them in a progress bar or a graph. graph, bars or progress for every month and also for the end of year. Actually this is the last module of my project and after this i will be left very very few things, please help me in completing my project..!!

Comment: Ten - twenty  minutes

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge for your answer, but it is giving an error Property "CDbCriteria.param" is not defined.

Comment: @SalikAsad  yes . a mistake is params and not param . i have update the answer

Comment: Oh thank you so much @scaisEdge it is working fine, thank you very much. Just need to ask that as one month ends it will automatically create a div for the next month and will show the  top 5 users, am i right..??

Comment: In this case the loop is from 1 to 12 but you can evaluate if use date('m') instead of 12..

Comment: This means if i use date('m') instead of 12, it will create a div for the current month and when a new month comes the previous month stats will remain at it's place and a new div will be created with the stats of the current month.

Comment: Yes... Just a curiosity you are student?

Comment: yes i am just a student and learning things and i must say, you are very helpful and a great man.