# Yii: How to show dynamic bootstrap progress bars on view page

Tags: php, yii

I am a yiibie. I have top 5 ngo's on my view page(top 5 ngo's for each month) and also the top 5 ngo's at the end of the year on the same page. Now i want to show the bootstrap progress bar in front of every ngo. For example if January is the month and it is showing me top 5 ngo's of that month,I want to show a progress bar in front of all those 5 ngo's and I want it for every month. And same thing for the end of the year. Like the 1st ngo progress bar will be 100%, 2nd ngo will have less then 100% and so on. Please help me in doing this, thank you.
This is my code for my controller which has the view file function

```
           public function actionNgostats()
{

    $this->layout='main';
    $myCurrYear = date("Y");
    $userYear=UserRateReviewNgo::model()->findAll(array(
        'condition' => 'YEAR(date_created)=:year',
        'params' => array(':year'=>$myCurrYear),
        'select'=>'DISTINCT rate,ngo_id',
        'order'=>'rate DESC',
        'limit' =>  5
     ));  
    $this->render('ngostats', array("userYear"=>$userYear));
}
```

and this is my view file(ngostats)

```
    <div>
    <?php
    for($month = 1 ; $month <=date('m') ; $month++) 
    {

     $user=UserRateReviewNgo::model()->findAll(array(
            'condition' => 'YEAR(date_created)=:year and MONTH(date_created)=:month',
            'params' => array(':year'=>2015, ':month'=>$month),
            'select'=>'DISTINCT rate,ngo_id',
        'order'=>'rate DESC',
        'limit' =>  5
         )); 
     foreach($user as $show) {
            $model = Ngo::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$show->ngo_id,));
            if (isset($model)) {

?>
<div><h4><?php echo $model->ngo_name?></h4></div>
 <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"
  aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">
    40%
  </div>
</div>

<?php
    }}}
?>
   </div> 


<h3>This is for the year's top 5 Ngo's</h3>
<div>   
    <?php // the for the year 
        foreach($userYear as $show) {
            $model = Ngo::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$show->ngo_id,));
            if (isset($model)) {
            ?>
    <div><h4><?php echo $model->ngo_name?></h4></div>
 <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"
  aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">
    40% Complete (success)
  </div>
</div>
    <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: what is your goal? please explain in  simple way and with a comprensible example what you need

Comment: I just want to show the top 5 ngo's of every month in a graph or a progress bar or a bar chart, anyone of it which is easy and possible.

Comment: OK  but which value you want show in the progress bar?

Comment: Like if it's a bar chart then the 1st top ngo has the highest bar or if it's a graph then the the 1st top ngo is on the highest point of if it's a progress bar then the 1st top ngo should have the highest percentage.

Comment: I want to show the percentage in the progress bar, like if it is the 1st top ngo then it should show 100% in the progress bar, if it's the 2nd then it should show 80% in the progress bar and so on. I hope you understand mate, and thanks for the response.

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge, can you please have a look at this in your free time, thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552034/yii-image-repetition-upon-image-uploading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for the month i hope you are able to adapt for the year

Is simple at begin the var $val is set to 100 and this value is assigned where it is needed then is decremented by 20 and the cycle is repeated

```
 <div>
    <?php
    for($month = 1 ; $month <=date('m') ; $month++) 
    {

        $dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $month);
        $monthName = $dateObj->format('F'); 
        echo "<h3> " . $monthName . "</h3>"; 

        $user=UserRateReviewNgo::model()->findAll(array(
            'condition' => 'YEAR(date_created)=:year and MONTH(date_created)=:month',
            'params' => array(':year'=>2015, ':month'=>$month),
            'select'=>'DISTINCT rate,ngo_id',
        'order'=>'rate DESC',
        'limit' =>  5
         )); 
        $val = 100;
        foreach($user as $show) {

            $model = Ngo::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$show->ngo_id,));
            if (isset($model)) {
                echo "<div><h4>" . $model->ngo_name ."</h4></div>
                    <div class='progress'>
                    <div class='progress-bar progress-bar-striped active' role='progressbar'
                    aria-valuenow='" . $val ."' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: ". $val ."%;'>" .  $val .
                    "</div>
                    </div>";
                    $val = $val -20;
    }}}
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh yes thanks mate it worked, i will use the same thing for the year, and please can you tell me how to print the month name on the top of the div, because when i do so it comes in the loop and the month gets printed with each ngo name.

Comment: I have update the answer .. but anyway i suggest  a few google search eg: "php how get the name of month" .....

Comment: I did it mate but i just gave me the month name over and over againn..!!