# Yii: Image repetition upon image uploading

Tags: php, yii

I am a yiibie and i have used [Yii 1.1: How to upload image(photo), and path entry in database with update functionality](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/349/how-to-upload-image-photo-and-path-entry-in-database-with-update-functionality) using this link and I followed everything everything from this link `http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/349/how-to-upload-image-photo-and-path-entry-in-database-with-update-functionality/`. Now the problem is that when I upload an image for my `Ngo profile`, on change of image of one Ngo profile the profile image of other Ngo's also gets changed. For example I have an `Ngo A` with image `ngo1.jpg` and `Ngo B` with `ngo2.jpg`. When i update the profile of `Ngo A` with `ngo3.jpg` it gets changed but also changes the image of `Ngo B` to `ngo3.jpg`. And also none of any Ngo is getting deleted. When i delete it it gives an error which says

```
Error 500: <h1>CDbException</h1>
<p>CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`response_system`.`user_rate_review_ngo`, CONSTRAINT `fk_user_rate_review_ngo_ngo1` FOREIGN KEY (`ngo_id`) REFERENCES `ngo` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION). The SQL statement executed was: DELETE FROM `ngo` WHERE `ngo`.`id`=5 (C:\wamp\apps\yii\db\CDbCommand.php:357)</p><pre>#0 C:\wamp\apps\yii\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php(1745): CDbCommand->execute(). Please help me with this.
```

This is my Ngo model

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "ngo".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'ngo':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $ngo_name
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $address
 * @property string $image
 * @property string $requirement
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property ClaimedNgo[] $claimedNgos
 * @property UserRateReviewNgo[] $userRateReviewNgos
 */
class Ngo extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return Ngo the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'ngo';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('ngo_name, email, address, image, requirement', 'required'),
            array('ngo_name, email, image', 'length', 'max'=>45),
            array('address', 'length', 'max'=>100),
            array('requirement', 'length', 'max'=>500),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, ngo_name, email, address, image, requirement', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
                array('image', 'length', 'max'=>255, 'on'=>'insert,update'),
                    );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'claimedNgos' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ClaimedNgo', 'ngo_id'),
            'userRateReviewNgos' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserRateReviewNgo', 'ngo_id'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'ngo_name' => 'Ngo Name',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'address' => 'Address',
            'image' => 'Image',
            'requirement' => 'Requirement',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('ngo_name',$this->ngo_name,true);
        $criteria->compare('email',$this->email,true);
        $criteria->compare('address',$this->address,true);
        $criteria->compare('image',$this->image,true);
        $criteria->compare('requirement',$this->requirement,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
}
```

This is my `Ngo Controller`

```
<?php

class NgoController extends RController
{
    /**
    * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
    * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
    */
    public $layout='//layouts/admin';
        public $pageOwner;
    /**
    * @return array action filters
    */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
//          'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
//          'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request

                    'rights',
                );
    }

    /**
    * Specifies the access control rules.
    * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
    * @return array access control rules
    */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
    * Displays a particular model.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
    */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }
        public function actionNgopage($id)
    {         
               $this->layout='main';
               $model2=new UserRateReviewNgo();
        $this->render('ngopage',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
                         'reviewmodel'=>$model2// This is for rate and reviewing
        ));
    }
       public function actionAllngo()
{
    $allmodels= Ngo::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'id DESC'));
    $this->layout='main';
    $this->render('allngo',array('allmodels'=>$allmodels));
}
public function actionEditcomment()
{

//               $this->layout='main';            //render main layout
//                $model2=new UserRateReviewNgo();   //new objecct of table ratereviewngo
//              $this->render('editcomment',array(
//          'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),   //model+reviewmodel as a object 
//                  'reviewmodel'=>$model2// This is for rate and reviewing
//                        ));

               //Yahan se hum ne kaam shuru kia he comment wala
              $this->layout='main';
                    $rbmodel=  UserRateReviewNgo::model()->findAll();
                    $u_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
                    $biz_id=$_GET['ngo_id'];
                    $rev_id=$_GET['rbid'];
                  //select rating,review from review_business where user_id=1 and id=6
                  $results = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                ->select('r.rate,r.review,r.id,r.user_id')
                ->from('user_rate_review_ngo r')
                ->where('r.user_id='.$u_id) //checking/comparing the current user
                ->andWhere('r.id='.$rev_id)//matching the review here 
                ->queryAll();
              $this->render('editcomment',array(
        "u_id"=>$u_id,"biz_id"=>$biz_id,"results"=>$results,"rev_id"=>$rev_id,"rbmodel"=>$rbmodel,

        )); 
    }  




    /**
    * Creates a new model.
    * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Ngo;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Ngo']))
        {
                     $rnd = rand(0,9999);  // generate random number between 0-9999
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Ngo'];
                        $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            $fileName = "{$rnd}-{$uploadedFile}";  // random number + file name
            $model->image = $fileName;
            if($model->save())
                            {
                $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../img/'.$fileName);  // image will uplode to rootDirectory/event/
                $this->redirect(array('admin'));
            }
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Updates a particular model.
    * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
    */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {

            $this->layout='owner';
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
                     $claimed=1;                      
                //The Query is select the userid,and claimed field from claim business, where 
               //userid= currently logged in user and the field of claimed is equal to means, it has been claimed, and the right hass 
              //been given to owner. so only that owner can now view the update page.
                    $current_user=YII::app()->user->id;
                    $results = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                    ->select('b.user_id,b.ngo_id,b.claimed')
                    ->from('claimed_ngo b')
                    ->where('b.user_id='.$current_user) //getting the current logged in user,and the claimed business bit
                    ->andWhere('b.claimed='.$claimed)
                     ->queryALL();

                   if(isset($_POST['Ngo']))
        {
            //$model->attributes=$_POST['Business'];

                    $_POST['Ngo']['image'] = $model->image;
                    $model->attributes=$_POST['Ngo']; 
                    $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');

                    if($model->save())
                    {    
                        if(!empty($uploadedFile))  // check if uploaded file is set or not
                    { 
                        $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../img/'.$model->image);
                    } 
                   $this->redirect(array('/ngo/ngopage?id='.$model->id));
                    }

                    }
              //var_dump($results);
                       if($results=='')                                     //empty means, if admin is coming or someone else
            {                                                               //layout-controller-model render view
            $this->pageOwner=$results[0]['ngo_id'];                   //by var_dump i know the position of busines_id

               $this->render('update',array('model'=>$model, 'results'=>$results));            //sending results
                    }
                            else                                                    // if admin or owner comes, 
                                                                                    // even if else not works, i still have made arrangement in update
                            { 
                                $this->pageOwner=$id;
                            $this->render('update',array('model'=>$model, 'results'=>$results));

                            }

        }

    /**
    * Deletes a particular model.
    * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
    */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
        {
            // we only allow deletion via POST request
            $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

            // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
            if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
        }
        else
            throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
    }


    /**
    * Lists all models.
    */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Ngo');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Manages all models.
    */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new Ngo('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Ngo']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Ngo'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
    * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
    * @return Ngo the loaded model
    * @throws CHttpException
    */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=Ngo::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    /**
    * Performs the AJAX validation.
    * @param Ngo $model the model to be validated
    */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='ngo-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my `view file`

```
<?php
/* @var $this NgoController */
/* @var $model Ngo */
/* @var $form BSActiveForm */
?>

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.BsActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'ngo-form',
    // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
    // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
    // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
    // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ),
)); ?>

    <p class="help-block">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'ngo_name',array('maxlength'=>45)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'email',array('maxlength'=>45)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'address',array('maxlength'=>100)); ?>
    <?php //echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'image',array('maxlength'=>45)); ?>
     <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'image'); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'image'); ?>  <!--by this we can upload image-->
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'image'); ?>
</div>
    <?php if($model->isNewRecord!='1') ?>
    <div class="row">
     <?php echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/img/'.$model->image,"",array("width"=>200)); ?>  <!--Image shown here if page is update page-->
</div>
    <br>
    <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'requirement',array('maxlength'=>200)); ?>

    <?php echo BsHtml::submitButton('Submit', array('color' => BsHtml::BUTTON_COLOR_PRIMARY)); ?>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Please Help me, thank you.

Comment: This question is related to the actionUpdate of the NgoController?

Comment: The code indicating how "this is my view files" is code for "view/ ngo/update"?

Comment: Thanks mate for the response, but the issue got resolved..

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge can you please help me with this if you get free, thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34564999/yii-unable-to-delete-the-things-from-the-admin-panel

Answer (score -1):

```
 <?php echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/img/'.$model->image,"image",array("width"=>200)); ?>  <!--Image shown here if page is update page-->
```

Try this

Comment: and it is not deleting the record, because you havent applied cascading