# Yii: Unable to delete the things from the admin panel

Tags: php, yii

I am a yiibie and I am having a problem that any event that I am trying to delete is not getting deleted and it gives me an error which is

```
Error 500: <h1>CDbException</h1>
<p>CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`response_system`.`user_join_event`, CONSTRAINT `fk_user_join_event_event1` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `event` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION). The SQL statement executed was: DELETE FROM `event` WHERE `event`.`id`=18 (C:\wamp\apps\yii\db\CDbCommand.php:357)</p><pre>#0 C:\wamp\apps\yii\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php(1745): CDbCommand->execute().
```

I can easily update the event like I can update the image but I am not able to delete it.
This is my `EventController`

```
class EventController extends RController
{
    /**
    * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
    * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
    */
    public $layout='//layouts/admin';

    /**
    * @return array action filters
    */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
//          'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
//          'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
                    'rights',
        );
    }

    /**
    * Specifies the access control rules.
    * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
    * @return array access control rules
    */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
    * Displays a particular model.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
    */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }

        public function actionAllevent()
        {
            $allmodels=Event::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'id DESC'));
            $this->layout='main';
            $this->render('allevent' ,array('allmodels'=>$allmodels));

        }


    /**
    * Creates a new model.
    * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Event;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Event']))
        {
                     $rnd = rand(0,9999);  // generate random number between 0-9999
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Event'];
                         $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            $fileName = "{$rnd}-{$uploadedFile}";  // random number + file name
            $model->image = $fileName;
            if($model->save())
                             {
                $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../img/'.$fileName);  // image will uplode to rootDirectory/event/
                $this->redirect(array('admin'));
            }
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Updates a particular model.
    * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
    */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Event']))
        {
                    $_POST['Event']['image'] = $model->image;
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Event'];
                        $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');

            if($model->save())
                            {
                if(!empty($uploadedFile))  // check if uploaded file is set or not
                {
                 $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../img/'.$model->image);
                }
                $this->redirect(array('admin'));
            }
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Deletes a particular model.
    * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
    */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
        {
            // we only allow deletion via POST request
            $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

            // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
            if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
        }
        else
            throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
    }

    /**
    * Lists all models.
    */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Event');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Manages all models.
    */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new Event('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Event']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Event'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
    * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
    * @return Event the loaded model
    * @throws CHttpException
    */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=Event::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    /**
    * Performs the AJAX validation.
    * @param Event $model the model to be validated
    */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='event-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my `Event model`

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "event".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'event':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $image
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property UserJoinEvent[] $userJoinEvents
 */
class Event extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return Event the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'event';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
                return array(
            array('image', 'required'),
            array('image', 'length', 'max'=>45),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, image', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
                    // this will allow empty field when page is update (remember here i create scenario update) 
                    array('image', 'file','types'=>'jpg, gif, png, mp4', 'allowEmpty'=>true, 'safe'=>false, 'on'=>'insert,update'),
                    array('image', 'length', 'max'=>255, 'on'=>'insert,update'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'userJoinEvents' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserJoinEvent', 'event_event_id'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'image' => 'Image',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('image',$this->image,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
}
```

And this is my `view file(_form.php)`

```
<?php
/* @var $this EventController */
/* @var $model Event */
/* @var $form BSActiveForm */
?>

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.BsActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'event-form',
    // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
    // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
    // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
    // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    //form options array...
'htmlOptions' => array(
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ),
)); 

?>

    <p class="help-block">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <?php //echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'image',array('maxlength'=>45)); ?>
    <!--this is for data path entry-->
      <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'image'); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'image'); ?>  <!--by this we can upload image-->
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'image'); ?>
</div>
    <?php if($model->isNewRecord!='1') ?>
    <div class="row">
     <?php echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/img/'.$model->image,"",array("width"=>200)); ?>  <!--Image shown here if page is update page-->
</div>
    <br>
    <?php echo BsHtml::submitButton('Submit', array('color' => BsHtml::BUTTON_COLOR_PRIMARY)); ?>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

This is the structure of the `userjoinevent` table
 Table structure for table `user_join_event`

```
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_join_event` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `event_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_modified` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_user_join_event_user1_idx` (`user_id`),
  KEY `fk_user_join_event_event1_idx` (`event_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=91 ;
```

And this is the constraint for table

```
ALTER TABLE `user_join_event`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_user_join_event_event1` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `event` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_user_join_event_user1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

And this is the UserJoinEvent model

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "user_join_event".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'user_join_event':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $user_id
 * @property integer $event_id
 * @property string $date_created
 * @property string $date_modified
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property Event $event
 * @property User $user
 */
class UserJoinEvent extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return UserJoinEvent the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'user_join_event';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('user_id, event_id', 'required'),
            array('user_id, event_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('date_created, date_modified', 'length', 'max'=>45),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, user_id, event_id, date_created, date_modified', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),

                     array('date_modified','default', 'value'=>new CDbExpression('NOW()'),//automatically add the current date in mysql feild
                     'setOnEmpty'=>false,'on'=>'update'),
                   array('date_created,date_modified','default', 'value'=>new CDbExpression('NOW()'),'setOnEmpty'=>false,'on'=>'insert'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'event' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Event', 'event_id'),
            'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'user_id' => 'User',
            'event_id' => 'Event',
            'date_created' => 'Date Created',
            'date_modified' => 'Date Modified',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('user_id',$this->user_id);
        $criteria->compare('event_id',$this->event_id);
        $criteria->compare('date_created',$this->date_created,true);
        $criteria->compare('date_modified',$this->date_modified,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
}
```

Please help me with this, thank you.

Comment: Show me the schema of the related table' user_join_event' . I need to know the foreign key of the link beetween this table and event .. And Just for my curiosity why do you need this constrain..?

Comment: I have updated my code with the structure of the table. Every thing was just going week few days and i dont know why things have stopped working of my project

Comment: I have posted an aswer.  i hope this is useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem is related to the fact you have Eevent link to User Event by the table user_join_event. then when you try to delete an Event the DB raise an error because in the way some row of user_join_event remain without reference. 
This implies that before deleting the Event is mandatory delete the releted child. (I suggesti you of do a copy of the table before executing the code)

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
    {
        // we only allow deletion via POST request
        $modelUserEvents = UserJoinEvent::model()->findAllByAttributes( array('event_id'=>$id));
        if isset($modelUserEvents){
            foreach($modelUserEvents as $child){
                $child->delete();
            }
        }
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }
    else
        throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, it dont any error now but it does not delete the event.

Comment: Just a minor i have corrected the foeach in foreach.. i think you have already done this.. please confirm me..

Comment: Yes i have already done it.. and also missing brackets with isset and findallbyattributes

Comment: I have update the answer (big mistake) i forgot the Model Name  .. UserJoinEvent i guess..

Comment: It still gives an error 500 "nonstatic method Cactiverecord::findAllbyAttributes() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context". This error is on the the line where you have used the model name

Comment: I have update the answer.. try again .. i'm doing  four others think in multi tasking... and .... do error

Comment: Still an error undefined variable:model in the event controller where we have defined the UserJoinEvent model name... I see that we have wrote the correct model name

Comment: Are you sure you have a model UserJoinEvent .. check for the proper name? or you don't have this model or similar.?

Comment: Yes I have the proper model name "UserJoinEvent" and i have checked it... I dont know why it is giving this error

Comment: Show me the model  UserJoinEvent (UserJoinEvent.php in protected/model

Comment: I have find the problem, i have update the answer.. ($id and not $model->id)

Comment: Thanks mate for the response but There is still some problem. I is now showing nothing when i click on the delete button. I have updated the question with the model

Comment: Well now the delete in database should happen.. the fatc you don't see nothing is related to the fact you tested for a GET ajax but the delete are alway on post (remove the if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))) and leave only the redirect..

Comment: still nothing happened.. Nothing gets deleted. I also tried to delete it from my db manuall but it gives this error 1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`response_system`.`user_join_event`, CONSTRAINT `fk_user_join_event_event1` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `event` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Comment: How do you check if the db row are deleted ?

Comment: I go to phpmy admin and delete the row from the userjoinevent table, but it shows this error..!! Please help, I am very worried.

Comment: Oh yes mate, it got deleted, thanks for the answer. The problem was that the { brackets were not correctly aligned, i just gave spaces and properly aligned the code and it deleted.. You are the best, Thanks again. I have one more question to ask, I will try it by myself, if it not happens I will post it.

Comment: please have a look when you are free, thank you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574457/yii-admin-unable-to-update-things-from-admin-panel

Answer (score 0):

you have relation with UserJoinEvent table, and the error cause from the restrictions, so delete rows from UserJoinEvent table (parent table)

Comment: Which rows should I delete? And I have to delete from the userjoinevent parent table which in this case is the event table? Am I right..??

Comment: I think you have to delete parent of this event (18).