# Yii: Admin unable to update things from admin panel

Tags: php, yii

I am a Yiibie and I am having a problem that when the admin tries to update the Ngo's profile, It just don't get updated, when changes are made and submit is presses it goes to the view file but don't show the updates. PLease help me with this. This is the code for my `NgoController`

```
   <?php

class NgoController extends RController
{
    /**
    * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
    * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
    */
    public $layout='//layouts/admin';
        public $pageOwner;
    /**
    * @return array action filters
    */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
//          'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
//          'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request

                    'rights',
                );
    }

    /**
    * Specifies the access control rules.
    * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
    * @return array access control rules
    */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
    * Displays a particular model.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
    */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }
        public function actionNgopage($id)
    {         
               $this->layout='main';
               $model2=new UserRateReviewNgo();
        $this->render('ngopage',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
                         'reviewmodel'=>$model2// This is for rate and reviewing
        ));
    }
       public function actionAllngo()
{
    $allmodels= Ngo::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'id DESC'));
    $this->layout='main';
    $this->render('allngo',array('allmodels'=>$allmodels));

}
public function actionEditcomment()
{

//               $this->layout='main';            //render main layout
//                $model2=new UserRateReviewNgo();   //new objecct of table ratereviewngo
//              $this->render('editcomment',array(
//          'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),   //model+reviewmodel as a object 
//                  'reviewmodel'=>$model2// This is for rate and reviewing
//                        ));

               //Yahan se hum ne kaam shuru kia he comment wala
              $this->layout='main';
                    $rbmodel=  UserRateReviewNgo::model()->findAll();
                    $u_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
                    $biz_id=$_GET['ngo_id'];
                    $rev_id=$_GET['rbid'];
                  //select rating,review from review_business where user_id=1 and id=6
                  $results = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                ->select('r.rate,r.review,r.id,r.user_id')
                ->from('user_rate_review_ngo r')
                ->where('r.user_id='.$u_id) //checking/comparing the current user
                ->andWhere('r.id='.$rev_id)//matching the review here 
                ->queryAll();
              $this->render('editcomment',array(
        "u_id"=>$u_id,"biz_id"=>$biz_id,"results"=>$results,"rev_id"=>$rev_id,"rbmodel"=>$rbmodel,

        )); 
    }  




    /**
    * Creates a new model.
    * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Ngo;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Ngo']))
        {
                     $rnd = rand(0,9999);  // generate random number between 0-9999
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Ngo'];
                        $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            $fileName = "{$rnd}-{$uploadedFile}";  // random number + file name
            $model->image = $fileName;
            if($model->save())
                            {
                $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../img/'.$fileName);  // image will uplode to rootDirectory/event/
                $this->redirect(array('admin'));
            }
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

/**
 * Updates a particular model.
 * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
 */
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $this->layout='owner';
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);
    $claimed=1;                      
    $current_user=YII::app()->user->id;
    $results = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
       ->select('b.user_id,b.ngo_id,b.claimed')
       ->from('claimed_ngo b')
       ->where('b.user_id='.$current_user) 
       ->andWhere('b.claimed='.$claimed)
        ->queryALL();

    if(isset($_POST['Ngo'])) {
       $_POST['NGO']['image'] = $model->image;
       $model->attributes=$_POST['NGO'];
       $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
       $fileName = "{$uploadedFile}";  
       $model->image = $fileName;           
       if($model->save()) {
            if(!empty($uploadedFile)) {
                uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../img/'.$model->image);
            }
            $this->redirect(array('admin'));
        }
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }           
    if($results=='') {     
        $this->pageOwner=$results[0]['ngo_id'];                   
        $this->render('update',array('model'=>$model, 'results'=>$results));           
    } else { 
       $this->pageOwner=$id;
       $this->render('update',array('model'=>$model, 'results'=>$results));
    }
}

    /**
    * Deletes a particular model.
    * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
    */
    public function actionDelete($id)
{
    if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
    {
        // we only allow deletion via POST request
        $modelUserNgo = ClaimedNgo::model()->findAllByAttributes( array('ngo_id'=>$id));
        if (isset($modelUserNgo))
            {
            foreach($modelUserNgo as $child)
                {
                $child->delete();
            }
        }
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser

            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));

    }  
    else
        throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');


}


    /**
    * Lists all models.
    */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Ngo');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Manages all models.
    */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new Ngo('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Ngo']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Ngo'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
    * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
    * @return Ngo the loaded model
    * @throws CHttpException
    */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=Ngo::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    /**
    * Performs the AJAX validation.
    * @param Ngo $model the model to be validated
    */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='ngo-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the view file(_form.php)

```
<?php
/* @var $this NgoController */
/* @var $model Ngo */
/* @var $form BSActiveForm */
?>

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.BsActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'ngo-form',
    // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
    // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
    // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
    // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ),
)); ?>

    <p class="help-block">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'ngo_name',array('maxlength'=>45)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'email',array('maxlength'=>45)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'address',array('maxlength'=>100)); ?>
    <?php //echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'image',array('maxlength'=>45)); ?>
     <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'image'); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'image'); ?>  <!--by this we can upload image-->
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'image'); ?>
</div>
    <?php if($model->isNewRecord!='1') ?>
    <div class="row">
     <?php echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/img/'.$model->image,"image",array("width"=>200)); ?>  <!--Image shown here if page is update page-->
</div>
    <br>
    <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'requirement',array('maxlength'=>200)); ?>

    <?php echo BsHtml::submitButton('Submit', array('color' => BsHtml::BUTTON_COLOR_PRIMARY)); ?>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

And this is the `Ngo model`

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "ngo".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'ngo':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $ngo_name
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $address
 * @property string $image
 * @property string $requirement
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property ClaimedNgo[] $claimedNgos
 * @property UserRateReviewNgo[] $userRateReviewNgos
 */
class Ngo extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return Ngo the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'ngo';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('ngo_name, email, address, image, requirement', 'required'),
            array('ngo_name, email, image', 'length', 'max'=>45),
            array('address', 'length', 'max'=>100),
            array('requirement', 'length', 'max'=>500),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, ngo_name, email, address, image, requirement', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
                array('image', 'length', 'max'=>255, 'on'=>'insert,update'),
                    );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'claimedNgos' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ClaimedNgo', 'ngo_id'),
            'userRateReviewNgos' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserRateReviewNgo', 'ngo_id'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'ngo_name' => 'Ngo Name',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'address' => 'Address',
            'image' => 'Image',
            'requirement' => 'Requirement',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('ngo_name',$this->ngo_name,true);
        $criteria->compare('email',$this->email,true);
        $criteria->compare('address',$this->address,true);
        $criteria->compare('image',$this->image,true);
        $criteria->compare('requirement',$this->requirement,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: @please format the actionUpdate in a ordered and more easily  readble way .

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have updated the the update function

Comment: Now is properly formatted.. ! But anyway  When you do submit,  the action is redirected to admin or to view . be sure of the right answer..

Comment: when i submit it goes to the localhost/projectname/ngo/view?id=(Id of the ngo that has been edited)... and no updation is shown on this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are redirect to view  but the updated value are non saved this mean something in save operation dosen't work

You can try  (just for debug) to  use

```
 if($model->save(false)) {
```

and in this way you see   if without validation the model is saved and the program is redirect to admin.

like suggested by @fal you can properly check $modelgetErrors() eg

```
var_dump($model->getErrors());  //for evaluate the eventual error
```

If the problem is this (related to the validation) then provide the correct validation or the correct value.

Comment: I have posted an answer.. I hope this could be useful.  i think @fal also show you a right way for find the solution.

Comment: can you please help me with this if you are free, thank youhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595749/yii-repetition-of-data-in-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Try to check result of $model->save() or $model->getErrors() in the Controller. Hope this will help :)