# Yii: Repetition of data in sql query

Tags: php, yii

I am a Yiibie and I have a question that I have a query which gives me the top 5 Ngo's of every month based on the rating of the ngo. But the problem is that Ngo's name are repeated in the top 5 and I want that ngo's name should not be repeated in the list of top 5 ngo's. Here is the view file.

```
              <div class="main">
    <div class="banner">
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseurl;?>/img/stat1.jpg" style="width: 1170px">
</div><!--banner ending here--><br>
    <div class="container" style="background-color:#7AC5CD">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3 style='text-align:center; text-decoration: underline;font-family: sans-serif; color: black'>Top 5 Ngo's month wise</h3>
        <br>
    <?php
    for($month = 1 ; $month <=12 ; $month++) 
    {
        '<br>' ;
        $dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $month);
        $monthName = $dateObj->format('F'); 
        echo "<h3 style='text-align:center;color:black;'> " . $monthName . "</h3>"; 

        $user=UserRateReviewNgo::model()->findAll(array(
            'condition' => 'YEAR(date_created)=:year and MONTH(date_created)=:month',
            'params' => array(':year'=>2016, ':month'=>$month),
            'select'=>'DISTINCT rate,ngo_id',
        'order'=>'rate DESC',
        'limit' =>  5
         )); 
        $val = 100;
        foreach($user as $show) {

            $model = Ngo::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$show->ngo_id,));
            if (isset($model)) {
                echo "<div><h4><a href='".Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/ngo/ngopage?id=$model->id'><p style='color:black;font-family:Lucida Sans Unicode;'>" . $model->ngo_name ."</p></a></h4></div>


                    <div class='progress'>
                    <div class='progress-bar  progress-bar-danger progress-bar-striped active' role='progressbar'
                    aria-valuenow='" . $val ."' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: ". $val ."%;'>" .  $val .
                    "</div>
                    </div>";
                    $val = $val -21.23;


    }  }}

    ?>
        </div>

             <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">   
                 <h3 style='text-align:center; text-decoration: underline;font-family: sans-serif; color: black'>Top 5 Ngo's of the year</h3>
<br>   
 <?php // the for the year 
    $val = 100;
        foreach($userYear as $show)
            {
            $model = Ngo::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$show->ngo_id,));
            if (isset($model)) 
                {
               echo "<div><h4><a href='".Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/ngo/ngopage?id=$model->id'><p style='color:black; font-family:Lucida Sans Unicode;'>" . $model->ngo_name ."</p></a></h4></div>


                    <div class='progress'>
                    <div class='progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active' role='progressbar'
                    aria-valuenow='" . $val ."' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: ". $val ."%;'>" .  $val .
                    "</div>
                    </div>";
                    $val = $val -17.96;

            } 

        }
    ?>
</div>
            </div>
        </div><!--main ending here-->

</div><!--Container ending here-->
```

Please help me with this, thank you.

Comment: This is the query with which you get no_id & rate .. should give the 5 ngo_id with the highest rate right? also let me see the code where you use these models ($ users) .. The controller and / or the view where you use this data

Comment: This is the code of my view file, I have updated the code, hope this will help.

Comment: And yes I want 5 Ngo_id with the highest rate.

Comment: Is not complete i don't see the } for closing the if and the foeach ..You're telling me you want to get 5 different names and instead get the same name. Try to see if ngo_id is different or is always the same ... Because at first glance the code to display the name seem right.

Comment: Okay let me update the question with my whole view file. The ngo_id some times get different and sometimes are same. I have updated the code.

Comment: But when the ngo_id is different  you see a proper diffrent name  not the same ..ever.. right?

Comment: Yes when the ngo_id is different i see the proper different name

Comment: The problem is just with the query to get the top ngo's. It just sometimes gets the ngo name twice or thrice in the top 5 ngo's list. I just want that the ngo name just doesn't get repeated in the top 5 list. Thanks for the response mate

Comment: well then the problem is in the data. Your  query is for the first 5 rate but could be you want the 5 top max(rate) .. if is so .. tell me so i can post a proper answer and you can rate it

Comment: Yes I want th 5 Ngo's with the maximun rating.or can i get the top 5 ngo's based on there average rating..??

Comment: I have posted adn aswer .. this query should obtain the 5 most rated ngo ...remain the fact  you have  some ngo with rate in several position. With this query  these are not showed..

Comment: Thanks it worked, and what i I want the top 5 most rated Ngo's for the year should I use the same query with max(rate) or there will be some other way..?

Comment: Exactly. and jJust a little advice, if I may, deepens always good querying the database, if you can find the right quary the problem is always much easier. SQL is a powerful tool .. but very sophisticated and know it well takes much, much study and attempts. You must learn to think in terms of set theory and not only procedural

Comment: Ok mate, thanks for the advice, much appeciated..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the 5 most rate ngo you should use this query

```
$user=UserRateReviewNgo::model()->findAll(array(
        'condition' => 'YEAR(date_created)=:year and MONTH(date_created)=:month',
        'params' => array(':year'=>2016, ':month'=>$month),
        'select'=>'max(rate),ngo_id',
        'group' => 'ngo_id',
    'order'=>'rate DESC',
    'limit' =>  5
     ));
```

Comment: hi @scaisEdge can you please help me with this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34683142/yii-show-message-when-the-search-filed-is-empty-and-submit-is-pressed

Comment: hi mate, I just need to ask one more thing related to this question which is that how can i get the top 5 Ngo's on the basis of there average rating. Like the SQL should find the average rating of all the NGO and display the 5 ngo's which have the highest average rating..!! Or should I post another question for this..

Comment: For me is more easy eval a new question without confusing with previous consideration.. and a new  question had more possibilty of help by the community..

Comment: Okay let me put a question for this..!!

Comment: i have posted the question, please see if you are free, thankyou http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34686082/yii-getting-data-on-the-basis-of-highest-average-rating