# Yii: show message when the search filed is empty and submit is pressed

Tags: php, yii

I am a Yiibie, and I want that when my search filed is empty and submit button is pressed it shows me the message on my screen to fill the field first. 
Here is code for the search bar

```
   <?php
/* @var $this VolunteerFormController */
/* @var $model VolunteerForm */
?>
<?php $roles=Rights::getAssignedRoles(Yii::app()->user->Id);
foreach($roles as $role) 
{ 
if($role->name == 'Admin')
{?><!--till here is done so that if the user is admin the view will be shown and if it not an admin 
   only the message will be shown which we have written in the bottom, same we have done for the user fill the volunteer form-->


<?php
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Volunteer Forms'=>array('index'),
    $model->id,
);

$this->menu=array(
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-list','label'=>'List VolunteerForm', 'url'=>array('index')),
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign','label'=>'Create VolunteerForm', 'url'=>array('create')),
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-edit','label'=>'Update VolunteerForm', 'url'=>array('update', 'id'=>$model->id)),
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign','label'=>'Delete VolunteerForm', 'url'=>'#', 'linkOptions'=>array('submit'=>array('delete','id'=>$model->id),'confirm'=>'Are you sure you want to delete this item?')),
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-tasks','label'=>'Manage VolunteerForm', 'url'=>array('admin')),
);
?>

<?php echo BsHtml::pageHeader('View','VolunteerForm '.$model->id) ?>

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView',array(
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'class' => 'table table-striped table-condensed table-hover',
    ),
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'id',
        'team_name',
        'name_of_ngo',
        'email',
        'address',
        'no_of_members',
        'experience',
        'user_id',
    ),
)); ?>
<?php }
if($role->name=='Authenticated')
{?>
 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <div class="alert alert-success">
  <strong>Congrats!</strong> You have signed up for Volunteering, You will be contacted soon..!!.
</div>
     <?php

        }     
}
?>
```

Please help me with this, thank you.

Comment: Hi Salik Asad.. i have posted an answer but you need JQuery and the id of the field to check..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need JQuery   and the id of the fields you need to check (change YourIdOfTheFieldToEval with the right value)

You can find the id in FireFox pressing CTRL +u and inspectt the source page code.. or via .. firebugs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('form').submit(function () {

  // Get the value and trim it
   var field1 = $.trim($('#YourIdOfTheFieldToEval1').val());

   // Check if empty of not
   if (field1=== '') {
       alert('Text-field is empty.');
       return false;
   }

  // Get the value and trim it
   var field2 = $.trim($('#YourIdOfTheFieldToEval2').val());

   // Check if empty of not
   if (field2=== '') {
       alert('Text-field is empty.');
       return false;
   }
   // repeat for the fields you need to check 
   .......

 });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge what if I have multiple fileds and any of the filed goes missing it should display a message, can you tell please. I have updated the question.

Comment: @SalikAsad I have update the answer.. it's enough repeat the code for the fields you need..

Comment: Thanks bro, I just have to ask one more question.

Comment: Hi @SaliikAsad   .   ..but you never sleep? Do the question  eventually I answer tomorrow

Comment: Actually I have my final presentation tomorrow and I am having some small problems which I have to deal with for tonight. So i might not sleep tonight..!!